# InterstitialAd not working with Windows Phone 10 (UWP - Windows 10)

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I cant' get `InterstitialAd` to work in my UWP app when running on the Windows Phone Emulator (Note that I haven't tried it yet on actual real phone)

It works as expected when I run my UWP app in the Simulator or Local Machine as a Windows Store app.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**UPDATE - 1**

Here is the code I use to display the InterstitialAd. In my MainPage.xaml.cs I have the following code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Instantiate the interstitial video ad
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd();

        // Attach event handlers
        interstitialAd.ErrorOccurred += OnAdError;
        interstitialAd.AdReady += OnAdReady;
        interstitialAd.Cancelled += OnAdCancelled;
        interstitialAd.Completed += OnAdCompleted;
    }
}

// This is an event handler for the interstitial ad. It is 
// triggered when the interstitial ad is ready to play.
private void OnAdReady(object sender, object e)
{
    // The ad is ready to show; show it.
    interstitialAd.Show();
}

// This is an event handler for the interstitial ad. It is 
// triggered when the interstitial ad is cancelled.
private void OnAdCancelled(object sender, object e)
{
}

// This is an event handler for the interstitial ad. It is 
// triggered when the interstitial ad has completed playback.
private void OnAdCompleted(object sender, object e)
{
}

// This is an error handler for the interstitial ad.
private void OnAdError(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)
{
}
```

I've literarily taken this code from their UWP Store sample except that instead of launching this from a button, I'm launching it when my page is loaded:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Request an ad. When the ad is ready to show, 
    // the AdReady event will fire.

    // The application id and ad unit id are passed in here.
    // The application id and ad unit id can be obtained from Dev 
    // Center.
    // See "Monetize with Ads" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/
    // en-us/library/windows/apps/mt170658.aspx
#if DEBUG
    interstitialAd.RequestAd(AdType.Video, 
    "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab", "11389925");
#else
    interstitialAd.RequestAd(AdType.Video, 
    "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab", "11389925");
#endif
}
```

I've left both ApplicationId and UnitAdId as the test values for the time being as I haven't released it yet, well, not with ads anyway.

Thanks

**UPDATE - 2:**

I've added some debugging logs in the various events and this is what I get:

```
Page_Loaded: 00:00:00.0001590
Page_Loaded - RequestAd: 00:00:00.0091840
OnAdReady - Elasped Time: 00:01:04.6923865
OnAdError: NetworkConnectionFailure : Media timeout occurred 
                                      during playback. - Elasped 
                                      Time: 00:00:08.1955928
```

It takes over 1 minute for the OnAdReady to be triggered which is really odd and then I get an OnAdError 8 seconds later so from these logs you would assume that there is a network problem but my data is being loaded correctly which is all pulled from a web service, so there is definitely a connection. Also my AdMediator displays Ads as expected (well, kind of! That's another story!).

I will try to transfer it directly to my phone tomorrow and see if it makes any differences and I plug in my laptop to an Ethernet port instead of using the wireless but my wireless is pretty decent, so I'm not sure why I'm getting network connectivity errors.

Comment: Please provide some more details. Details like - how you implemented InterstitialAd etc

Comment: @VineetChoudhary I've added the code I'm using. Hope this helps figure out the problem. Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to put breakpoint in `private void OnAdError(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)` method. It's may be due to some error occurs during the loading of ads.

Comment: @VineetChoudhary I've updated my answer again.

Comment: I'm also facing same error in my demo project.

Comment: After my machine crashes (WIN10 - Blue screen) and I rebooted, I went straight in VS and ran my app in the emulator and I was surprised to see it actually worked but it still does take over a minute to be launched but it did display a video. I'll get in touch with Microsoft and hopefully they'll get back to me. If they do, I'll update this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is correct and does actually work with UWP on Windows Phone but it doesn't work great in the emulator as:

- it intermittently generates network connectivity errors when they are none.
- it can take over a minute to display the advert but it eventually will.

I've just uploaded my app to the store and downloaded it to my phone and it works as expected. It displays the advert immediately or within a couple of seconds or so.

I would recommend you do not waste too much time trying it via the phone emulator as it appears to be the main problem. Implement your code and then test it directly on your device or download it from the store assuming you haven't released your app yet.

**UPDATE:**

I just thought I'd update my answer as I was just reading about the do's and dont's with interstitial adverts from [UI and User Experience Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt313119.aspx)  and the way I'm actually doing it, is one of points in the "avoid" list.

It recommends that you fetch the advert 30-60 seconds ahead of time and you don't display it when the app starts, which is what I'm doing, so I guess I will change the logic in that regards.

Comment: Warning! pre-fetching an advert ahead of time can get your app blacklisted by buyers (due to how the RTB market works). 60 seconds is pushing it.

Comment: @James, Just quoted what MS are saying but thanks for sharing this point. I guess as advised, it's probably best to use the default i.e. 30 seconds.

Comment: techqa.info, candoerz.com, and SO... where else have you asked the same question? PS. I have the same problem, but not in Emulator, but on the Local machine itself... Do you think problem is with Ad servers?

Comment: @VijayChavda I haven't asked the question anywhere else. These website are obviously pulling the question from SO. It's been a long time since I looked at that but from what I recall is that it did work but it ads may not be available in your region causing the phone not to display anything.